# Problem with copy in Windows 7 and my C# program

Tags: c#, windows-7

I do this in my C# program:

```
File.copy(Application.StartupPath + "\Test.txt",@"c:\Test.txt");
```

But I get this error:

```
Access to  the path 'c\Test.txt' is denied
```

It happens only in Windows 7,  in Windows XP it works excellent.

Comment: I dont know how that error can be more clear :) Appaerently you don't have the rights to create the file there.

Comment: The right way is to store any user-related files in user's profile. Storing any files at root directory is bad idea on any system. If you really want that - change the program so it request Administrator rights to run. This is done by messing with manifest

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Access is denied. That means you don't have access. No, really, it does.

User accounts in Windows 7 are limited (non-Administrator) by default, so your program cannot just write anywhere on the system (and that is a Good Thing (TM)). Try putting `Test.txt` in another directory, for example the temp directory (ask the system where that is).

Comment: and how to force this copy in C# (is there any class that deal with) ?
(if it can be doing)

Comment: If you could force it, that would make security privileges rather useless, wouldn't it? But you can request elevated privileges, if you must. The user will then be asked for approval, with the dark gray screen and all that. I have never done this, but read up on UAC if you really want to do this. (I wouldn't want any app to request this just for writing a Test.txt into the C: root!)

Answer (score 2):

Win 7 blocks root folder on system drive...
put the file in a place you have permissions to copy.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others said try using [Special Folders](http://dotnetperls.com/environment-specialfolder). and learn a little bit about [Making Your Application UAC Aware](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/MakingAppsUACAware.aspx?msg=2623884)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 **don't allow to access the program folders** and the root folder. 
You can give the Directory writer access or change the destination path to one user Folder, like the "My Documents" or an App Directory.

You can loacate this paths with Environment.GetFolderPath();

**Example**

Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
*retrurns:* "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming"

Answer (score 1):

It's best to join a file & path with Path.Join

```
File.copy(Path.Join(Application.StartupPath, "\Test.txt"), @"c:\Test.txt");
```